# Creating a separate timeline in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

When I find interesting posts I share them and they appear in my timeline. In time, I get a lot of posts in my timeline. I would like to split them and to have a distinct timeline where I can keep only the posts containing videos. All those posts are not created by me, they are posts I found in my Facebook page, created by the people I follow.

How can I create a separate timeline where to keep only the video posts?

Comment: No. You can't do that on Facebook.

Comment: Thanks. So I have to create another account if I want to have a place dedicated only to videos or to a certain topic. I have the feeling that there are already many accounts made just for that. Which is quite a waste of space and an unnecessary inflation of the number of accounts.

Comment: Technically, creating a second personal account (or worse yet, an account with a fake name) is a violation of Facebook's TOS.  Please see the answer I posted for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you could create one or more Facebook Pages to which you could then share these posts (even if this is not the "traditional" use-case for setting up a Page).

Each such Page could be named according to its respective topic, and could be categorized in one of many different ways: for example, under "Other"/"Just For Fun."

Pages, like personal accounts, each have their own Wall / Time Line. Keep in mind that Pages are, by definition, public entities; thus, you will not be able to make certain posts private (as you can on a personal Wall). On the other hand, if you are interested in sharing this Timeline with others, then Pages have the advantage of not being limited to a maximum number of fans (as opposed to personal accounts, which are limited to a maximum of 5,000 Friends).